# Xcode 4 automator plugin

Tags: xcode, automation, xcode4

If I want something to happen with a file after I save it in Xcode 4, is there any way I can achieve that? Say I want to replace all occurrences of "a" with "b" in the file after saving it.

Can this be done using the Automator? Or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires file/directory observation:

You could either use an **Objective-C wrapper for FSEvents**, such as **[SCEvent](https://github.com/hooleyhoop/HooleyBits/blob/f661151edcc0f436d939e77c251a184bb6683638/FolderWatcher/SCEvent.h)**

Or you could use Uli Kusterer's **[UKKQueue](http://zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm)**, which is an **Objective-C wrapper around the kqueue** file change notification mechanism.

Similarly to **UKKQueue** there exists Google's **[GTMFileSystemKQueue](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMFileSystemKQueue.h)** which as well is an **Objective-C wrapper around kqueues**.

In short:

- **FSEvents** inform you about **changes within an observed directory**
- **kqueues** inform you about **changes with an observed file**

---

**To get an xcodeproj's files (which you then want to observe) parse its internal xml content tree.**

Comment: The problem with many of these frameworks is they do not handle safe saves! When modifying a file in Preview it creates one or more temporary files that eventually replace the original file.  These temp files are registered as file creation events.